# Move to next pending request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web application where users can submit a request to be given access to certain systems. When they visit their pending approvals page, they are presented a list of requests that they need to make a decision on.

Pending Requests:

[image: Pending Requests]

When they click view on each request, they are taken to a details page where they can then Approve or Reject the request.

Approve / Reject

[image: Approve / Reject]

Once they click Approve or Reject the request, they are redirected back to the page containing all pending requests.

**AJAX CALL**

```
        $('#approve').click(function (e)
    {
        $("#approve").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#reject").attr("disabled", true);
        // Submit the form
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: '_ApproveRequest',
            type: $('#SubmitForm').attr('method'),
            data: $('#SubmitForm').serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data)
                {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ShowApproverRequests", "AccessRequest")';
            }
        });
    });
```

**My Question**

Is it possible for me to redirect the user to the next pending request, if one exists, when they either approve or reject a request? If there is NOT another pending request, they should be returned to the original "ShowApproverRequests" page that the ajax call currently directs to.

Comment: Yes you could, your action method handling approve/reject could check the list and then return something to say where to go. Or actually, since you always redirect after your ajax call, it would make more sense not to use ajax, and then the server could immediately specify a redirect to the correct item. The whole point of ajax is to avoid postbacks and redirects. In your case, by doing a window.location.href immediately when ajax completes, you lost the main benefit of ajax.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. This particular application was inherited on my part. Not sure why it currently uses Ajax, but perhaps I'll move away from it. Or, given your comment, I may HAVE to move away from it.

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but it would make more sense in this situation